# cloudera manager cluster installation step5 (Installing Selected Parcels ) stuck

Tags: hadoop

I use the vmware provided by the official website to add a new cluster action and try to use two nodes for deploy. Repeating it several times is always stuck at this stage and i can't find the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19ZO8.jpg)

please help,and thank you。

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I solved it, thank you.